# Get value as undefined when using '@' in directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, angularjs-directive

I've created one directive with isolated scope and try to assign value using '@' symbol.
For. e.g. Directive Looks like this.

xyz.js

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

angular.directive('xyz', function($http, $timeout, $ocLazyLoad) {
   return {
       restrict: 'AE',
       templateUrl: 'urlPATH',
       scope: {
       name : '=',
       maxCount: "@"
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
       scope.maxCount = scope.maxCount == undefined ? "1" : scope.maxCount;
       console.log(scope.maxCount) //Onload of the page it print 1 
       console.log(scope) // Onload it will print whole **scope** object with value of      **maxCount** is *undefined*.
       // The function which is call on keyup event defined in template.
       //For e.g.
       scope.getUrl = function(){
       console.log(scope.maxCount)
    }
}
```

template.html

```html
<div style="display:block;">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="margin-bottom:-8px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm lookup-drop dropdown ">
                    <input  type="text" class="form-control clearable " ng-model="xyz.name" ng-keyup="getUrl()" >
                </div>
               </div>
           </div>
     </div>
```

If use the directive in **test.jsp**  like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<xyz  name="test" max-count="10"></xyz>
```

then on keyup event console will look like this.

> 10

If use the directive in **test.jsp**  like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<xyz  name="test" ></xyz>
```

then on keyup event console will look like this.

> *undefined*

I don't get any idea why this is happened. Is there anything that I have forgot, if so then please let me know.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scope.maxCount` is bound to your attribute and can be thought of as read-only. Try another variable instead:

```
scope.max = scope.maxCount || "1";
/* use scope.max instead of scope.maxCount */
```

alternatively, instead of binding to scope, read from attributes:

```
scope.maxCount = attributes.maxCount || "1";
```

.. and remove `maxCount: "@"` from your scope mapping.

Comment: Same thing that I have done for giving immediate solution.
Other thing we can do is redefine the with `maxCount : "=?"`.
but I want to know the root cause, why it so happened??